# .htaccess rewrite rule explained (simple)

Tags: .htaccess

```
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule MATCHME https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

IF MATCHME is not in the URL then will the RewriteRule NOT Be processed? Could you link me to some documentation?

Comment: [Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (see the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. If the pattern `MATCHME` is not present, no rewriting will take place.

If you require a catch-all rule to be matched when your `RewriteCond` is active, you can specify an additional rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule MATCHME https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
# Catch-all rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/someotherpage [L,R,QSA]
```

Review the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).